# Invalid field or parameter requestInfo.url

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

I am trying to get users blog post (newsfeed blog posts) which are located on same web application as other site collections  and show them within a web part by using JavaScript.

I use `SP.RequestExecutor` to make a cross domain request. My code is as follows. I have tested the query in IE and it worked perfectly. But when I run the code it generates

> Invalid field or parameter requestInfo.url

```
var url1= "http://temp.com/personal/username/blog/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?$select=Title, Id, Created&$orderby=Created desc&$top=1";
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
executor.executeAsync({

    url: url1,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("ok");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(xhr));
    }
});
```

When  I use `var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor("http://temp.com/personal/username/blog");` instead of `var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);` it goes to error callback and says `responseAvailable:false, body: "", headres:null`

My Site host Site Collection is on the same web application, still getting same error.

Comment: You are looking like you are the on the right track with your code, but before I dive in I always google first and this was already a set of topics on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appsforsharepoint/thread/34927fcf-5cf5-485e-b459-e3161735a96b Take a look there if you find your answer please post a reply and mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you, I have already read it. but I don't understand. the answer suggests that the guy has old bits. what it means? and I am not using Apps. my case is usual javascript no apps at all.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from other posts, you should encode the url parameter in base64. You could try this :

`url: encodeURIComponent(url1)`

Or, if you're writing Mozilla or Chrome specific code, then you can use `btoa()` and `atob()` to convert to and from base64 encoding.

I also prefer to remove all white spaces from REST endpoints like this : 
`var url1= "http://temp.com/personal/username/blog/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?$select=Title,Id,Created&$top=1";`

- Remove white spaces between parameters (to avoid %20 in the url)
- Remove the orderby just to test, if it works, then try again with the orderby.

Comment: hi and thanks, I have removed the white spaces and orderby and used encodeURIComponent. this time it goes to the error call back and says "Bad Request".

Comment: Normally when you get a Bad Request you should get more informations. Try printing all the error function parameters.

Comment: I don't get details about the error it says "a specific error happend on the server ..." and " I have to change the CustomError in the web.config to see more details of the error. I cannot change the web.config file.

Comment: Add data to your error handler as well.  It should give more info as to the error, I believe in data.body.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `SP.RequestExecutor.js`, I'm going to assume this is a SharePoint hosted app.

First, try getting the appweburl from the query string (decode it), and passing that to the `RequestExecutor` constructor.

Second, change the url you're using for the REST call.  Try this:

```
var url1 = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?$select=Title,Id,Created&$orderby=Created desc&$top=1@target='" + encodeUriComponent(hostweburl) + "'";
```